# Not sure about smart pointers C++

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers, raw-pointer

I'm new to C++, I would like to ask about the code below. Lets say we have class A, then class B that is child class of A. Then we have ohter class C, I want this class to be able to own either A object or B object. I used template for that. I'm not sure whether it is good approach. Also my other question is I read that using owning raw pointers is a bad practice, so how can I use smart pointers here? Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {

public:
  int x;
  A(int i){x = i;};
  virtual int f(){return x;};
};



class B : public A {
public:
  B(int i): A(i){};
  int f() {return x*2;};
};



class C {
  int y;
  A *pointer = nullptr;     // it can points to A or B object, how can I implement in this code smart pointer unique_ptr<A> pointer
public:
  C(int i): y(i){};

  template <typename T>
  void ff(T &object){ pointer = &object;};

  void fff() {cout <<  pointer -> f() << endl;};
  };



 int main(){
   A a(3);
   B b(4);
   C c(2);
   c.ff(b);   
   c.fff();  
   c.ff(a);
   c.fff();

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Your template is unnecessary `void ff(A &object){ pointer = &object;}` compiles perfectly well and will work with `B` objects as well.

Comment: This looks fine, apart from `using namespace std;`. You do not need any smart pointer here because `c` does not own `a` nor `c`, `main` does.

Comment: In this case there is no need for smart pointers because you are not dynamically allocating any objects.

Comment: `C` doesnt appear to own the instances. If you merely need to point to something, then a raw pointer is fine. Ownership is only about who is responsible for destroying the instance and in your example noone has to call `delete`.

Comment: perhaps explain what is the aim of the code. What are you actually trying to achieve? The code is fine, but if you want/need something else is not quite clear

Comment: @abc Please refer to my answer's edit